# Word for an object being extended: Given F, a function that extends F is called an extension and F is called the extension __?

Tags: terminology

If a field L extends a subfield K then L is called an **extension** of K and K is called the extension's **base field**. See [extension field](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extension_field#English) for a definition.

What is the analog of "base field" when it's a function being extended?

That is, if a function L [extends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) a given function K then L is called an **extension** of K and the original function K is called the extension's **____?**.

The word "[restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics))" does not work because no one calls K "the extension's restriction" and I don't want to make up new terminology that no one else uses. Whenever the word "restriction" is applied to a function, then the set that it is being restricted to is always either explicitly mentioned or else clear from context. For example, people often write "the function's restriction to this-or-that set", and if the set is clear from context then they *might* simply refer to it as "the function's restriction". But (at least based on my Internet searches), no one writes "the function's restriction" without somehow making clear the set that it is being restricted to.

Example usage:

> If an extension has the same [this-or-that property] as its ______ then they will also have the same [this-or-that property].

What word fits in the blank?

More generally, we have a noun ("extension") for any thing produced by an act of extending. Is there a noun for the thing that is going to be extended (before the act occurs)?

Comment: What's the matter with _base function_? If you substitute _function_ for _field_ in the definition, why not in the name, too?

Comment: "I don't want to make up new terminology that no one else uses." You'll likely find a better answer on math.SE. This isn't about English per se, but about the jargon used in a particular field.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @John Lawler I have not seen there term "base function" used in this way and I don't want to make up terminology.

Comment: Although I have large exposure to people writing about function extensions, I haven't seen a specific term for that. Either people use everyday English (_the original function_, for example), or use the name of the function (usually, the extension of $f$ is denoted by $\overline{f}$, $\tilde{f}$ or something similar, to make things simpler).

Comment: I read something that used "pre-extension", but I don't know how common it is. [Googling would suggest "not very".] Something like: *...if a function L extends a given function K then L is called an extension of K and the original function K is called a pre-extension of L.*

Comment: If there is a standard term, then math.stackexchange.com would be better. But perhaps there is no standard term, and it sounds like you're trying to help your students understand by writing well about this. In that case, I think it does belong here.

Comment: I would say that the original function is the restriction of the extension. I think that's what most books say as well, if they say anything. The interesting thing is that for a given function, the restriction of any extension to the domain of the given function is the same. Still more interesting is how little one needs in particular contexts to uniquely prescribe an extension to the entire space. Like a basis in a vector space to fix a linear transformation, or a line-segment in complex analysis for an entire function, etc... I'm probably not helping :) Carry on.

Comment: Extending a function, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Dominique If f is the original function then I mean defining a new function F whose domain contains the domain of f and that is equal to f wherever they are both defined.

Comment: You can maybe not say that the original function is *the* restriction of its extension, but it's definitely *a* restriction of its extension. Also, when two functions take the same values on a common subset of their respective domains, we can say that these functions *coincide* on this common subset.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just say "the original function", having a pretty good colloquial sense, rather than create a technical word. Yes, if you are considering such stuff in a more extravagant way (e.g., in a vast category-theoretic setting), you might have a need to formalize this relationship, but, in my own experience, just the colloquial language is adequate. Or, in some modest examples, "restriction of the extension", but I've used this in situations where the "restriction" was not the original thing... For example, fooling around with unbounded self-adjoint operators (already in Sturm-Liouville problems, so it's not at all contrived).

Answer (score 2):

This might answer your question in a backwards way.

We have the notion of *germ equivalence* of two functions. Given a point $x$, we say that functions $f$ and $g$ define the same germ at $x$ if there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ (open set containing $x$) with $f\vert_{U}=g\vert_U$

Germ equivalence focuses on localization, as opposed to extension which is more of a global focus.